# OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers -32593

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting below exception while trying to insert records into database using CallableStatement.
Total records : 1300
To due to some security reasons not able to provide code snippet sorry for that but its normal CallableStatement executing perfectly for other flow in my project.

[image: Error Trace]

Throwing exception at 1327. stmt.executeBatch(). stmt is object of CallableStatement.

Comment: Doesn't matter how big a bounty you put on this, the problem is **your bespoke code** is throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and there's no way we can diagnose it without seeing the code in question. You need to post a reproducible test case you. What is the significance of `-32593` : that looks like something your program is outputting.

Comment: Totally agree with you guys, but because of some policies can't share it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem could be related with the Oracle JDBC driver [#6396242](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/2633177.html) bug: *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -32nnn*.

Please, try to download a patch for the bug from Oracle Support.

If you do not have access to Oracle Support, you can also download a recent version of the Oracle JDBC driver for your database version from the following [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbcdriver-ucp-downloads.html), it will also fix the problem.

Comment: Did I see what?  I saw the bug on Oracle's support website.  It looks like what the OP is encountering.

Comment: I mean you congratulated me on finding the problem, but I'm afraid that in the end I won't be the one to get the bounty. I hope that at least the user has fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  It's up to the OP who he awards the bounty to.  Hopefully he awards the answer he found most helpful rather than letting the system award it.

Comment: In fact, it does not matter Matthew, the important thing is that the user has been able to solve his problem.

Comment: On PROD batch job explicitly referring ojdbc 11.1. Now it changed to 11.2 and its working. Thanks all for help.

Comment: Great! I am very happy to know that the answer has been useful and that the problem in production has been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

An ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException could be thrown by the Oracle JDBC driver.

[**`Here`**](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=bug&id=6396242) you will get exact details of error from oracle.

It happens if the batch is too big. So either set the batch smaller in the OracleOutput component or try a different mode for inserting the data.

In order to resolve the issue, patch for BUG 6396242 must be downloaded from Oracle's support site and applied prior to using it.

You can resolve this problem by downloading the new version of ojdbc of 11 or greater version from [**`OJDBC`**](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbcdriver-ucp-downloads.html).

If you see this read me file here [**`BUG-6396242`**](ftp://aoa.edu.tr/CD/Oracle%20Servers/11/win32_11gR1_database_111070/database/stage/Components/oracle.dbjava.jdbc/11.1.0.7.0/1/DataFiles/Expanded/filegroup2/Readme.txt), it has been fixed in **`Oracle JDBC Drivers release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production`** version.

Here i had attached screenshot of same.[image: Bug]

Comment: Sorry, but could you tell me what the difference is with my answer? The important thing is that it is necessary to apply the indicated patch. I also have more information about it, but cannot provide it as it is subject to the license terms of Oracle and Oracle Support. I have only provided publicly accessible information. I think it is not appropriate to publish private links from Oracle Support and make public a document that is only accessible with the Oracle license as you have done.

Comment: @JoséCarlosCampanero , if you believe there is a violation in the Oracle support aggrement, flag the answer to "in need of moderator attention".

Comment: Thank you very much @RobertoHernandez. In fact, I already did. I don't know if it will be an explicit violation of the Oracle support license, but at least I think it is not proper behavior. In any case, I do not want to cause problems for anyone, and I prefer not to continue thinking about this matter, it is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the mysql driver it has been fixed in `5.1.13` more details [here]
[1](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43576), so to fix your bug simply upgrade it to the latest version.

Answer (score -2):

You've got a bug. It is in your code.

Go to file com.mypackage.accounts.server.util.UtilClass.

Go to line 1356.

On it, you will find at least 1 array access (i.e. `foo[x]`). The number inside the `[]`? It is -32593 for some reason. If there are more than 1 `[]` in that line, it's one of them, not possible to tell which one from this stacktrace.

Without you pasting the code we can't tell you why. I can tell you that PreparedStatement has nothing whatsoever to do with any of this.

Comment: On Line number 1327. stmt.executeBatch(). Here from actual error thrown. stmt is object of CallableStatement. Sorry for typo.